# Not Able to Import PyTorch in Conda Env

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, pytorch, conda

Last week I had a working conda env I was using for a project. I have not touched the project in a week. I just went to run a python file (`python file.py`) that had been running with no errors.

Now I get the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 2, in <module>
    from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

In an attempt to troubleshoot, I opened a python console and ran the following code:

```py
>>> import torch
```

The result was the following error message:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

If I check all the installed packages using `conda list -n <env_name>`, I can see that PyTorch is in fact installed, just as it was last week.

```
...
pytorch                   1.2.0           py3.7_cuda9.2.148_cudnn7.6.2_0    pytorch
...
torchvision               0.4.0                 py37_cu92    pytorch
...
```

Here is what I see when I start python console using `python`:

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
```

The output of `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)` in the base env is:

`['', '/home/<name>/anaconda3/lib/python37.zip', '/home/<name>/anaconda3/lib/python3.7', '/home/<name>/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/<name>/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages']` I have not personally made any chages to `PYTHONPATH`.

If I run `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'` with my conda env (non-base) active, I get:

`['', '/home/<name>/anaconda3/envs/<env_name>/lib/python37.zip', '/home/<name>/anaconda3/envs/<env_name>/lib/python3.7', '/home/<name>/anaconda3/envs/<env_name>/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/<name>/anaconda3/envs/<env_name>/lib/python3.7/site-packages']`

This is totally bizarre, can't figure out what is going on, and what could have happened, over the course of the last week, without me touching the code or making any changes to Anaconda.

Comment: Are you sure you're not in the base env, ie did you activate the environment?

Comment: Yes, I actually have three environments that have both pytorch and torchvision installed, none of them are working properly.

Comment: Do you have an `environment.yml` file that you can compare to the output of `conda env export > environment.yml` to see what changes there might be?

Comment: @merv I ran the command you suggested from both from my custom env and from the base conda env and added the output to the question.

Comment: @HMLDude thanks for adding that. That looks correct now, though. Before you didn't have `env_name` in the `sys.path`. Is it working now?

Comment: Yes, but only after taking the steps listed below. I am having a hard time understanding how everything was working a couple of weeks ago, and then it stopped working this week, without me making any changes in between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. open **anaconda-prompt** then run this

   `conda install PyTorch -c PyTorch`
2. If you didn't upgrade your pip.use this command to update

   `python -m pip install –upgrade pip`
3. After first step run this

   `pip3 install torchvision`

hope it will work.

Comment: The only thing that did not work was the second command you suggested. Instead I did `pip install --upgrade pip`. Otherwise, it all worked, thanks much! BTW, all these commands were executed in the specific conda env that was giving me trouble.

Comment: I got the same issue that you got. There for I was able to answer your question.Happy coding @HMLDude